# Load tensorflow SavedModel in Rstudio trained in Google Cloud ML

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I trained a model in Google Cloud ML and saved it as a saved model format. I've attached the directory for the saved model below.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18ivhz3dqdkvSQY-dZ32TRWGGW5JIjJJ1?usp=sharing

I am trying to load the model into R using the following code but it is returning `<tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable>` with an object size of 552 bytes, definetly not correct. If anyone can properly load the model, I would love to know how you did it. It should also be able to be loaded into python I assume, that could work too. The model was trained on GPU, not sure which tensorflow version. Thank you very much!

```
library(keras)

list.files("/path/to/inceptdual400OG")
og400<-load_model_tf("/path/to/inceptdual400OG")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the shared model is not available anymore (it says that is in the trash folder)and it is not specified in the question I can't tell which framework you used to save the model on first place. I will suggest trying [the Keras load function](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/reference/keras/save_model_hdf5/) or [the Tensorflow load function](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/keras/man/save_model_tf.html) depending on which type of saved file model you have.
Bear in mind modify this argument as "compile = FALSE" if you have the model already compiled.

Remember to import the latest libraries if you trained your model with tf>=2.0 because of dependencies incompatibilities {[Tensorflow](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tensorflow/index.html), [Keras](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/keras/index.html)} and rsconnect::appDependencies() output would be worth checking.